# OrderBy not working properly in firestore

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm facing with a **not so cool** problem and been thinking a way through it.
[image]

As in the above picture I'm using the timestamp field which has a timestamp datatype, to do a orderBy descending query.

[image]

After the query is done I need to enter the **Order Item** subcollection to get all the data.

```
CollectionReference orderRef = fStore.collection(Reference.ORDER_COL);
    orderRef.orderBy(Reference.TIME_STAMP, Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .whereEqualTo(Reference.CUSTOMER_UID, logInSession.getUID())
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot docSnap : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                            Log.e("TAG 1", "Loop 1");
                            final boolean packing = docSnap.getBoolean(Reference.STATUS_PACKING);
                            final boolean outForDelivery = docSnap.getBoolean(Reference.STATUS_OUT_FOR_DELIVERY);
                            final boolean delivered = docSnap.getBoolean(Reference.STATUS_DELIVERED);
                            final String orderDate = docSnap.getString(Reference.DATE);
                            final int totalAmount = docSnap.getLong(Reference.TOTAL_AMOUNT).intValue();
                            CollectionReference orderQuery = orderRef.document(docSnap.getId()).collection(Reference.ORDER_ITEM_COL);
                            orderQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                                    if (!value.isEmpty()) {
                                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot docSnap : value) {
                                            Log.d("TAG 2" , "Loop 2");
                                            String productName = docSnap.getString(Reference.PRODUCT);
                                            String totalPrice = String.valueOf(docSnap.getLong(Reference.PRICE).intValue());
                                            String quantity = String.valueOf(docSnap.getLong(Reference.QUANTITY).intValue());
                                            String thumbnail = docSnap.getString(Reference.THUMBNAIL);
                                            orderHistoryList.add(new OrderHistory(productName, thumbnail, quantity, totalPrice, orderDate, packing, outForDelivery, delivered));
                                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } else {
                        noOrderTxt.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(OrderActivity.this, R.anim.fade_in));
                        noOrderTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Above are the coding I did and the output I get is all messed up and is not queried on timestamp, there is also a **whereEqualTo()** method which is working fine.

As you can see I use **whereEqualTo()** and **orderBy()** and also have created the required Composite Indexes.

I place a log on both the **for** loops, here the first **for** loop executed first and then the second **for** loop came in which is confusing. I thought after the first for loop the second for loop will be executed but it didn't happen, not like the regular nested for loop it didn't work as I plan so I think that's the reason behind the messed up result I get on my app.

What I want is a proper DESCENDING **orderBy** query which I will be displaying to a **RecyclerView**.

Please help me out guys and thank you in advance. If you need anymore codes or details please tell me :)

Comment: I'm not understanding your problem entirely. Is this a method being called after you obtained other data in Firestore? Perhaps more code will be needed.

Comment: Have you created the corresponding indexes?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes i have created the indexes

Comment: @JamesFoster no other method is called here. The code that i added is the only get() method in that activity.

Comment: I think it is due to the asynchronous behaviour of Firebase . I think i need to sync those 2 get() method .

Comment: @AdhikarimayumKrishanta Firebase definitely has an asynchronous behaviour in the sense that you can (for example) submit Query One, Query Two and Query Three to Firestore, however they may not return the result in that same order. So you might need to sort your data after you have queried it.

Comment: On checking your orderBy code, it looks like the parameter is not right. You have ```orderRef.orderBy(Reference.TIME_STAMP, Query.Direction.DESCENDING)``` the Query.Direction doesn't have a ```.``` when specifying the direction,  so it would be ```orderRef.orderBy(Reference.TIME_STAMP, Query.Direction DESCENDING)```. You might also have an issue with the field/path itself as the method is polymorphic, so depending on the parameters put in the function it will try to decipher which orderBy you are using. Does Reference.TIME_STAMP return a String or a field path?

Comment: @MaryM `orderRef.orderBy(Reference.TIME_STAMP, Query.Direction.DESCENDING)` this is the correct way I have check it . `Reference.TIME_STAMP` where Reference is a class were is initialize all the constant fields that I will be using for firestore so `Reference.TIME_STAMP` is just a field name so its a string , it doesn't return anything . BTW thank you for your responsed and your time and also I have solved this problem so no more worries ;)